# Why i get error using get request angular?

Tags: angular, spring, visual-studio

I have a Spring Api with 2 tables:

1. Equipos
2. Jugadores

And each of equipos has a lot of jugadores.
When im using PostMan making a get a get the equipos and jugadores witout any aproblems but i am trying to get each equipos and put in into a div with Angular

1. Class Equipo
2. Equipo.ts
3. Equipo.component

equipo.ts :

```
export class  Equipo{    
    nombre:string;
    entrenador:string;
    escudo:string;    
}
```

equipo.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Equipo } from './equipo';const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'responseType': 'text',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}) 
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EquipoService {
    private usersUrl: string; 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8084/api/equipoes';
  } 
  public findAll(): Observable<Equipo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Equipo[]>(this.usersUrl,httpOptions)
  }
 }
```

equipo.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EquipoService} from '../equipo.service';
import { Equipo } from '../equipo';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-equipo',
  templateUrl: './equipo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./equipo.component.css']  
})
export class EquipoComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Equipo[]; 
  constructor(private userService: EquipoService) {
  } 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.findAll().subscribe(res => this.users = res);
  }

}
```

and equipo.component.html:

```
<div class ="test" *ngFor="let key of users">
    <h1>{{key.nombre}}</h1>
<div>
```

And a have this error:

> ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Datas:
[Datas from equipos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7NS.jpg)

Comment: what version of angular are you using and can you show what the data this.users looks like

Comment: Im using Angular 7. And the first data from Equipos is like :equipoes 
0 
nombre "Alavés"
entrenador "Abelardo Fernández"
escudo "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/sports/logos/football/png/72x72/173.png"
_links 
self 
href "http://localhost:8084/api/equipoes/1"
equipo 
href "http://localhost:8084/api/equipoes/1"
jugadores 
href "http://localhost:8084/api/equipoes/1/jugadores"

Comment: sorry for that...i just put a image with two equipoes dates